# Find Topology error in polygon layer

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, topology

I try to find topology error in this polygon layer using QGIS 2.18 with topology rule of "must not overlap":

[image]

but i don't understand why with the Topology checker, only several areas marked in red, whereas i expect that also other areas (i marked it with blue circle) will be defined as topology error:

[image]

this is the attribute table of the layer:

[image]

Comment: What rules do you have set up in the topology checker?

Comment: Can you share your test data and your topology rules?

Comment: how can i share the test data?